# How to stop laravel error(at-rule or selector expected)

Tags: html, css, laravel-5

[Error on public/app/app.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RscGn.png)

While i was just working on other stuff i found the error on this page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing selector, you just write property and value of CSS,

```
h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 80%;
}
```

h1 is selector, you can write here your class name or id name according to your project or program need.

Answer (score 0):

comment this line has solved the problem (vscode says it is a problem, not me) for me :

`/* @charset "UTF-8"; */`

NB: I think your css file is supposed to be in public/css/, not in public/app. Ideally and to respect the semantics, of course.

Comment: Comment out the charset declaration is not a solution. The problem is a different. As I see on the screenshot, the charset declaration in the CSS file is not the first element!

Following the specifications the charset declaration need to be the **first element** in the CSS file!